# How do I implement retries for WCF clients?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, polly, retry-logic

I have a C# client implementing `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>` for communication with a SOAP API.

I want the client to automatically retry requests when timeouts occur.

I figure I could use a library like Polly to create an HttpClient instance with a retry policy. 
However, I can't work out how to instantiate the WCF client with that HttpClient.

I'm also not sure if I'm meant to be using a different approach altogether, like creating a `IEndpointBehavior`.

It looks like there is a `CreateChannel` instance method that can be overridden and a `ConfigureEndpoint` static partial method that can be implemented, but I cant find any examples of how to use them correctly to implement retry either by using an instantiated HttpClient or via some other mechanism.

I've searched through the [docs for building clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/building-clients).  There are sections on [using channel factories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory), but it also doesn't seem to have a mechanism of supplying an HttpClient.

The [docs for expected exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/expected-exceptions) specifically mention `TimeoutException`, but the example just try/catches calls on the client.

I don't really want to do `RetryOnTimeout(client => client.MethodToRetryOnTimeout());`.  I know I can do that, and I know I can create a decorator that wraps all the client calls in similar logic. I just don't think that's the right approach.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Polly's retry is generic enough to be able to decorate any method (not just HttpClient's ones). Do you want to use retry for transient failure? What should be your trigger?

Comment: Yes, it’s for transient failures. It seems the API I’m calling spins down after a period of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `HttpClient` the `AddPolicyHandler` registers a `PolicyHttpMessageHandler`, which is a `DelegatingHandler`. It basically overrides the `SendAsync`:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
```

I haven't used WCF for awhile but if my memory serves well then the closest thing to this is the client message interceptor ( [`IClientMessageInterceptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)). Even though it is [feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022640/automatically-retry-client-wcf-call-based-on-interception-and-return-value) unfortunately it is not that easy to achieve.

Another alternative could be to use [`RealProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy?view=netframework-4.8.1). Basically here [you can override the `Invoke` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151361/wcf-retry-proxy) and decorate the `MethodBase`'s `Invoke` call with a policy which triggers for `TimeoutException` and `CommunicationException`. The problem with this approach is that `RealProxy` is not available in .NET Core (or its successor).

So, the only option is to wrap yourself the method calls. This can be done

- either with a generic static method (in your example the `RetryOnTimeout`)
- or by creating a custom `ClientBase` derived class

```
class ResilientSampleClient: ClientBase<ISampleClient>, ISampleClient
{
    private readonly IRetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<TimeoutException>()
            .Or<CommunicationException>)()
            .WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    public ResilientSampleClient(): base(binding, endpointAddress) {}

    public void MethodToRetryOnTimeout()     
       => retryPolicy.Execute(base.Channel.MethodToRetryOnTimeout);     
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

After spending a bit more time on `RealProxy` I've bumped into [this migration article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-realproxy-usage-to-dispatchproxy/). It suggests to use [`DispatchProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.dispatchproxy?view=net-8.0) instead.

I haven't tested this code, but based on the migration doc the [above `RealProxy` based solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy?view=netframework-4.8.1) could be rewritten like this:

```
public class WcfClientProxy<T> : DispatchProxy where T : class
{
    private readonly IRetryPolicy retryPolicy = Policy
            .Handle<TimeoutException>()
            .Or<CommunicationException>)()
            .WaitAndRetry(3, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            
    private readonly WcfChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory;

    public WcfClientProxy(WcfChannelFactory<T> channelFactory) : base()
    {
        this._channelFactory = channelFactory;
    }

    public override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args)
    {
        return retryPolicy.Execute(() => targetMethod.Invoke(this._channelFactory.CreateBaseChannel(), args));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm surprised I didn't come across that other answer.  Yes, I see what you mean that it doesn't look easy to achieve.  My only concern with using retries using wrapping, is that devs need to remember to implement that pattern as new endpoints are used.  Being able to rely on configuration would be preferable, but getting the immediate job done, this would be faster and easier.

Comment: @br3nt I've updated my post with a `DispatchProxy`-based solution which is the successor of the `RealProxy`.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-client-overview) for the instance wcf client. It goes through the details of creating a client.

Using polly Library to create an http client refer to [this article](https://duongnt.com/polly-retry-request/), which goes through the details of creating an instance in c# and lists the steps to create a client to see if it helps you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  My question is: How do I get the WCF client to use a provided HttpClient instance, or more generally, what is the "correct way" to implement retry logic for WCF clients.